# How to implement a custom search filter in AG Grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Let's say I have a function

```
customMatcher(userInput: string, valueInRecord: string): boolean
```

And I want to search the column using my customMatcher.

```
let coldefs = [
{
    headerName: 'Foo',
    field: 'foo',
    minWidth: 20
}]
```

How do I do that? I tried adding the `doesFilterPass` attribute with a simple function but that function was not getting called while searching. I am using Angular 8.3.29 and Node 16.14.2 if that matters.

Comment: Share more code [Stackblitz](http://www.stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for the `textMatcher` function which is used like this.

```
this.columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'foo',
        filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
            textMatcher: ({filter, value, filterText}) => {
                // custom matching logic that returns a boolean
                }
        }
    }
];
```

Relevant documentation [section](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-text/#text-custom-matcher).

Comment: Yeah, that works but the textMatcher feature was only added in ag-grid 27 and unfortunately, I'm not allowed to upgrade the version.

Comment: This is the same in a previous verison. https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.3.0/angular-grid/filter-text/#text-custom-comparator

Comment: Any option for version 22 ?

Comment: These are the docs for v22, looks like textCustomComparoator might be the same. https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/22.1.1/javascript-grid-filter-text/

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the `textMatcher` or `textCustom...` to work. what I ended up doing is

```
{
   field: 'number'
   filter: true,
   filterParams: {
       values: ['Even', 'Odd'],
       // this gets run for every row to see if it equals on of the values
       valueGetter: (params): string => {
           const data = params.data;
           return data.number % 2 === 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd';
          }
    }

}
```